# Error occurs whilst adding Pop-up Controller in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, controller

> // //  PopupViewController.h //  TheStore
>
> > // //  Created by Daniel Habshush on 11.04.15. //  Copyright (c) 2015
> >     H Company. All rights reserved. //

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface PopupViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *popUpView;

- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

> // //  PopupViewController.m //  TheStore // //  Created by Daniel
>   Habshush on 11.04.15. //  Copyright (c) 2015 H Company. All rights
>   reserved. //

```
#import "PopupViewController.h"

@interface PopupViewController ()

@end

@implementation PopupViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.6];
        self.popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        self.popUpView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
        self.popUpView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }
        - (void)showAnimate
        {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        self.view.alpha = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
        self.view.alpha = 1;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
        }

        - (void)removeAnimate
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }];
        }


- (IBAction)closePopup:(id)sender {
            [self removeAnimate];
        }

- (void)showInView:(UIView *)aView animated:(BOOL)animated
        {
            [aView addSubview:self.view];
            if (animated) {
                [self showAnimate];
            }
        }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
         }
@end
```

So, my question is:

I want to add a PopupView Controller to main.storyboard but can't somehow solve the last error.

Comment: Do you have a question? What's wrong. If you're getting an error, post it.

Comment: sorry i thought its own; following one;

Comment: /Users/danielhabshush/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/TheStore/TheStore/PopupViewController.m:35:17: Use of undeclared identifier 'removeAnimate'

Comment: on the line         - (void)removeAnimate

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing curly brace in your showAnimate method, which gives you an error in the following method.

Comment: stupid or because its 3 at night here in Europe after 10hours coding i cant see the missing brace :)